# checking queue manager status through Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, ibm-mq

I have to check the IBM MQ queue manager status before opening a queue.
I have to create requestor app by checking that the QMgr is active or not then call put msg or get message from MQ
Is it possible to check the status,

please share some code snippets.

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question or it will most likely be closed. Check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help.

Comment: Mani, more details will help. What exactly you want to check?  If you can connect to the qmgr then its fine (in terms of status)?

Comment: I've voted to close pending a response as to what exactly is driving the requirement to check status before putting a message. This smells of bad design. A monitoring app just connects and inquires on stuff.  A business app just connects and tries to put/get messages and handles exceptions. Mixing the two is almost always bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NEVER have to check the QMgr before opening a queue.  As I responded to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523259/how-to-get-number-of-consumers-connected-to-websphere-mq-queue-from-java/23532993#23532993) today, the design proposed is a very, VERY bad design. The effect is to turn async messaging back into synchronous messaging. This couples message producers to consumers, introduces location and resolution dependencies, breaks clustering, defeats WMQ's load distribution and balancing, embeds network topology into the application, and makes the whole system brittle. Please do not blame WMQ for not working correctly after intentionally defeating all its best features except the actual queue/dequeue operations.

If your requestor app is checking that the QMgr is active, you are *much* better off using a multi-instance connection name and a layer of two or more functionally equivalent QMgrs that can access the cluster.  So long as one of the QMgrs is up, the app will cycle between them until it finds one at which to connect.

If your responder app is checking that the QMgr is active, you are *much* better off just attempting to connect.  Responder apps should *never* fail over to a different QMgr since doing so breaks transactionality and may leave queues unserviced.  Instead just ensure that each queue has at least two input handles from local responder apps that do not fail over across QMgrs.  (It is OK if the QMgr itself fails over using hardware clustering or multi-instance QMgr though).

If the intent is to check that there's an open input handle on the queue before putting messages there a better design is to have the requesting app not care to which queue instance the messages are routed and instead use the instrumentation built into WMQ to either restart responder apps that lose their input handle, or to disable the queue when nothing's listening.

Comment: Thanks Rob, is it possible to share some code snippets which will give insights as to how should i check the Qmgr status before i can initiate any get or put messages

Comment: If you connect successfully, the status is good so go ahead and put messages.  If you get an error code trying to put messages, the error code will tell you why the put failed.  What more is needed?  Why do you want to check the status before putting messages and what, exactly, are you checking for?